# Copy value and paste under matching column near respective row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with certain values which are also the headers for some columns. I want to check where the column values match and paste the value from the first column into the column with the same column name. I have around 1200 values in the first column. I want to loop through those values and paste the matching values in the corresponding row.

[![Data][1]][1]

Here is my sheet with my data that I want to work on. How I want my final sheet to look like is as follows:

```
Weeks | W1 | W2 | W3 | W4 | W5 | W6
W1      W1
W3                W3
```

Any help for the same would be highly appreciated.

```
Sub Weeks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long, j As Long, Mas As Worksheet
Set Mas = Sheets("Master Sheet")

For i = 5 To 1200
    If Mas.Range("B" & i) <> "" Then
        If Mas.Range("AO" & i) = "Missing week" Then
            Mas.Range("AV" & i) = ""
            Mas.Range("AW" & i) = ""
            Mas.Range("AX" & i) = ""
            Mas.Range("AY" & i) = ""
            Mas.Range("AZ" & i) = ""
            Mas.Range("BA" & i) = ""
        Else
           For j = 5 To 1200
                If Mas.Range("AO" & i) = "W1" Then
                    Mas.Range("AV" & j) = "W1"
                    GoTo Nexti
            ElseIf Mas.Range("AO" & i) = "W2" Then
                    Mas.Range("AW" & j) = "W2"
                    GoTo Nexti
            ElseIf Mas.Range("AO" & i) = "W3" Then
                    Mas.Range("AX" & j) = "W3"
                    GoTo Nexti
            ElseIf Mas.Range("AO" & i) = "W4" Then
                    Mas.Range("AY" & j) = "W4"
                    GoTo Nexti
            ElseIf Mas.Range("AO" & i) = "W5" Then
                    Mas.Range("AZ" & j) = "W5"
                    GoTo Nexti
            ElseIf Mas.Range("AO" & i) = "W6" Then
                    Mas.Range("BA" & j) = "W6"
                    GoTo Nexti
            End If
            Next j
        End If
    End If
Nexti:
Next i
End Sub
```

This is the code I tried so far but it does not show any output.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is easy, store the column names with their column index in a `Dictionary` then input your whole range (7 columns and all the rows) into an array, loop through the array pasting the value on the first column on the index it match inside your dictionary, then paste the array back and there you go. Your data reordered in a split of a second.

Comment: I tried if else if statement but it is not working as I intended it to

Comment: Im not sure how to go about a dictionary. I am just getting started with VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you use the dictionary to achieve your goal:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Weeks()
            
    Dim Mas As Worksheet: Set Mas = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Sheet")
    With Mas
        'Calculate thelast row
        Dim i As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AO").End(xlUp).Row
        'insert your data into an array
        Dim arr As Variant: arr = .Range("AO5:BA" & LastRow).Value
        'Generate a dictionary with the headers
        'this needs the library Microsoft Scripting Runtime under Tools->References
        Dim Headers As Dictionary: Set Headers = LoadHeaders(.Range("AO4:BA4").Value)
        'Now loop through the array
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If Headers.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then arr(i, Headers(arr(i, 1))) = arr(i, 1)
            arr(i, 1) = vbNullString
        Next i
        .Range("AO5:BA" & LastRow).Value = arr
    End With
            

End Sub
Private Function LoadHeaders(arr As Variant) As Dictionary
    Set LoadHeaders = New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        LoadHeaders.Add arr(1, i), i
    Next i
End Function
```

You won't even need the `Application.ScreenUpdating`  because it does only one operation in Excel, will take a second or two to end this procedure.

Comment: I am getting the required output but it is also deleting the data in AO while sorting it. How can I avoid that and retain the data in AO?

Comment: @RohiniBaburaj just delete the `arr(i, 1) = vbNullString` part

Comment: Hi, I had another question. I have another column with some cash amounts in it. I want to do the same matching of the week values with the headers of weeks. But instead of copying the week values under the respective week columns, I want to copy the amount in the column beside it under the respective week column and corresponding row. How do I go about that? Please let me know if what I said is clear.

Comment: The amount values are in column AN that I want to be copied under the week columns where the weeks match

Comment: @Ro_Ba you need to get that column in the range and then change: `If Headers.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then arr(i, Headers(arr(i, 1))) = arr(i, 1)` the `arr(i, 1)` fir whatever index has the amounts.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Hey, I have one more question if you could help. What if I want to copy the weeks only for a certain period i.e., I have some periods in the column right next to weeks such as P01, P02, P03, etc. So I want to copy the weeks only for "P01" suppose. I tried ```If Headers.Exists(arr(i, 2)) And Mas.Range("AP" & j) = "P01" Then
                    arr(i, Headers(arr(i, 2))) = arr(i, 1)``` But this is still copying all the weeks and not just the weeks in P01.

Comment: You need to change `j` for `i` i = rows, j = columns. You are already giving the column with `"AP"` you need to give it the row number.

Comment: I declared j as ```For j = 5 To 1200```

Comment: Why would you change the code?? add the new column to the array and check for the value with the header you want as I did before...

Comment: The column is within the array. But it is not the same as the heading. I want to paste the same values as before just that I want it to be for the weeks within P01 only. I have values ranging from P01 to P12 in that periods column next to weeks. I want to paste the amounts in the various weeks matched where period is P01. I hope what I said is understandable

Comment: You can't use `Mas.Range` inside the array, you use `arr(i, ColumnNumber)` being ColumnNumber the index inside the array, count from 1 to that column where it is and check its value there.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in a module and link it to a button on the sheet.

```
'data
Cells.Clear
wks = Array("W1", "W2", "W3", "W4", "W5", "W6", "Missing week")
For i = 1 To 30
    Cells(i, 2) = wks(Int(Rnd * 7))
Next i

'code
Set weeks = [b:b]
For Each wk In weeks
    If Len(wk) = 2 Then Cells(wk.Row, Right(wk, 1) + 2) = wk
Next wk
```

`weeks` contains the column that has the list of column headings. The `For..Each` statement loops through each entry in this list.

Then it checks each entries string length. If it is length 2, it assumes the entry is valid (i.e of the form 'Wx' with `x` between 1 and 6), and then uses the inbuilt `Right` function to find the value of `x`, and then adds the appropriate entry into the appropriate column.

Comment: You need to place various "w1", "w2", .. , "missing week" entries into column B first.

Comment: I tried it but for some reason it didn't work for me. Thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: Thank you for your help :D But I got the required output from the previous answer!